# SQL, T-SQL. TRIGGER or PROCEDURE to duplicate the last row inserted by changing only some values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this:

```
|---------------PLAYERS-----------------|
| ID | NAME | GAMES | BUTTON | OPPONENT |
|---------------------------------------|
| 50 | BOB  | 00345 | RED    |   BIM    |
| 10 | JOHN | 00001 | YELLOW |   ALI    |
| 01 | ALI  | 00002 | GREEN  |   JOHN   |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93cc5/2

I need a TRIGGER or a PROCEDURE that when the new row contains in the column "BUTTON" the word "YELLOW" or "RED" then I want to duplicate the last row by changing only some values.

**EXAMPLE:**

I have this new row to write:

```
| 51 | JOHN | 00001 | YELLOW | MIKE |
```

With "yellow" button I want that the sql insert that row first and then a new row like this (Opponent column is NULL):

```
| 52 | JOHN | 00002 | YELLOW | NULL |
```

and another row like this (Mike is the opponent in the first row):

```
| 53 | MIKE | 00851 | YELLOW | NULL |
```

How to accomplish this?

Comment: How will the past rows come in the `inserted` table? What am I missing?

Comment: Dear @Raj, I removed my code that does not work. I'm here on Stack obviously know how to do and maybe someone like you enlightens me with a different idea.

Comment: Take a look at INSTEAD OF triggers: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175089(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to bear in mind that triggers in SQL Server run once for each statement - so there may be *multiple* rows in `inserted` (or no rows) and some of them may match your conditions and other not.

In this case, I think the cleanest thing to do is an `INSTEAD OF` trigger rather than an after trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_Players_I ON Players
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    ;With Dupl as (
       SELECT Name,Games,Button,Opponent,i
       FROM inserted
             cross join
            (select 0 union all select 1) t(i)
    )
    INSERT INTO Players (Name,Games,Button,Opponent)
    SELECT
       CASE WHEN Button IN ('Red','Yellow') AND i = 1 THEN Opponent ELSE Name END,
       Games,Button,
       CASE WHEN Button IN ('Red','Yellow') THEN NULL ELSE Opponent END
    FROM
       Dupl
    WHERE i = 0 OR Button IN ('Red','Yellow')
```

Comment: Dear @Damien, I need the first row (the new row) to be inserted and then I need the new rows with new values. So, I need the first insert and then the trigger. Is it clear now?